# datetime parameter between 3 datetime columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get my @from and @to to be between `SalesPos.startdate`,`SalesPosDamageH.CreatedTime`,`SalesPosReturnH.CreatedTime`
and I don't know how to write my where clause in that case.

I have tried multiple ways with no success.

This is my current attempt:

```sql
ALTER PROC rpt_Item_salesanalysis --rpt_Item_salesanalysis '2021-01-05 22:14:20.613','2022-02-02 12:05:38.183',null
    @from datetime = NULL,
    @to datetime = NULL,
    @barcode nvarchar(50) = NULL
AS
    SELECT GrpItm.nname AS GrpName,
           SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode,
           SalesPos_Dtls.ItemName,
           SalesPos_Dtls.TotalPrice AS DtlsAfterDiscountDtls,
           SalesPos_Dtls.NTotalPriceWithoutTax AS DtlsBFDiscountDtls,
           SalesPos_Dtls.OrderId AS countOrderID,
           SalesPosReturnD.ReturnPrice AS TotalReturnDtls,
           SalesPosReturnD.ItemID AS ReturnItemIDCount,
           SalesPosDamageD.ReturnPrice AS DamageTotalDTLs,
           SalesPosDamageD.ItemID AS CountFromDmg
    FROM GrpItm
         LEFT JOIN Itms ON Itms.nparent = GrpItm.nodeid
         LEFT JOIN SalesPos_Dtls ON SalesPos_Dtls.ItemId = Itms.nodeid
         INNER JOIN SalesPos ON SalesPos_Dtls.OrderId = SalesPos.ID
         LEFT JOIN SalesPosReturnH ON SalesPosReturnH.SalesPosID = SalesPos.ID
         LEFT JOIN SalesPosReturnD ON SalesPosReturnH.ID = SalesPosReturnD.SalesPosReturnID
                                  AND SalesPos_Dtls.ItemId = SalesPosReturnD.ItemID
         LEFT JOIN SalesPosDamageH ON SalesPosDamageH.SalesPosID = SalesPos.ID
         LEFT JOIN SalesPosDamageD ON SalesPosDamageD.SalesPosReturnID = SalesPosDamageH.ID
                                  AND SalesPos_Dtls.ItemId = SalesPosDamageD.ItemID
    WHERE ((@from <= SalesPos.startdate
        AND @from <= SalesPosDamageH.CreatedTime
        AND @from <= SalesPosReturnH.CreatedTime
         OR @from IS NULL)
       AND (@to >= SalesPos.startdate
        AND @to >= SalesPosDamageH.CreatedTime
        AND @to >= SalesPosReturnH.CreatedTime
         OR @to IS NULL))
      AND (@barcode = SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode
        OR @barcode IS NULL);
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you - simplify! [mcve]

Comment: Whitespace and Linebreaks are paramount to making readable text; not just in code. Please get into the habit of making good use of both. Poor/bad formatting is not going to help you or others when you need to be able to quickly read and understand your code. Using indentation and line breaks really helps easily distinguish specific code blocks and sections, and make finding errors far easier when a line only contains 10's of characters, rather than 100's. Your all left aligned text is very difficult to read.

Comment: Without sample data and DDL so we know what the relationships actually are, no one can really help you. All those outer joins make your join logic suspicious. And it seems to be your "createdtime" logic is backwards - you want something like <CreatedTime is between from and to>. But that is just a guess.

Comment: Also how can two date parameters be between three columns, what is the logic you are trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

When using `LEFT JOIN` one needs to watch out what's put in the `WHERE` clause.
Because it could make a `LEFT JOIN` behave like an `INNER JOIN`.

For example:

```
select *
from TableA a
left join TableB b ON b.a_id = a.a_id
where b.code = '42'
```

Will return exactly the same as:

```
select *
from TableA a
inner join TableB b ON b.a_id = a.a_id 
where b.code = '42'
```

But could be different if that extra criteria is in the `ON` clause:

```
select *
from TableA a
left join TableB b ON b.a_id = a.a_id AND b.code = '42'
```

This will at least return all from TableA.

So if you think some data is missing, it could be because it filters to much.

Also, `AND` is evaluated before `OR`.  So it's best to use parenthesis `()` when using both.

```
... 
FROM GrpItm
LEFT JOIN Itms 
  ON Itms.nparent = GrpItm.nodeid
LEFT JOIN SalesPos_Dtls 
  ON SalesPos_Dtls.ItemId = Itms.nodeid
 AND (@barcode IS NULL OR SalesPos_Dtls.ItemCode = @barcode) 
INNER JOIN SalesPos 
  ON  SalesPos.ID = SalesPos_Dtls.OrderId
 AND (@from IS NULL OR @from <= SalesPos.startdate)
 AND (@to IS NULL OR @to >= SalesPos.startdate)
LEFT JOIN SalesPosReturnH 
  ON SalesPosReturnH.SalesPosID = SalesPos.ID
 AND (@from IS NULL OR @from <= SalesPosReturnH.CreatedTime)
 AND (@to IS NULL OR @to >= SalesPosReturnH.CreatedTime)  
LEFT JOIN SalesPosReturnD 
  ON SalesPosReturnD.SalesPosReturnID = SalesPosReturnH.ID
 AND SalesPosReturnD.ItemID = SalesPos_Dtls.ItemId
LEFT JOIN SalesPosDamageH 
  ON SalesPosDamageH.SalesPosID = SalesPos.ID
 AND (@from IS NULL OR @from <= SalesPosDamageH.CreatedTime)
 AND (@to IS NULL OR @to >= SalesPosDamageH.CreatedTime)  
LEFT JOIN SalesPosDamageD 
  ON SalesPosDamageD.SalesPosReturnID = SalesPosDamageH.ID 
 AND SalesPosDamageD.ItemID = SalesPos_Dtls.ItemId;
```